# How to pass the ajax result to google maps

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

I am using this code to get the latitude and longitude of  current location.

```
<script>
var x=document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation()
  {
  if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
  else{x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";}
  }
function showPosition(position)
  {
  x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;    
  }
</script>
```

i need to pass the longitude and latitude from this ajax code to google map's LatLng variable how to this.

This is the google maps api code that i am using

```
    function initialize() {
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.000,17.1100);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 12,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
```

Can anyone help me..thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should just be a case of passing the lat and long that you've already retrieved:

```
function showPosition(position)
{
 var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
 var myOptions = {
  zoom: 12,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };

}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the same way you are currently, but passing in `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude` instead of `52.000` and `17.1100`.

```
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have initialized the map, you can center it after get the position:

```
map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function showPosition(position)
{
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + "<br />Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    initialize(position);
}

function initialize(position) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
    var myOptions = {
    zoom: 12,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
```